# Variable not initialized in C++ code?

Tags: c++, variables

Edit: Thank you all very much for your answers, I know now that this was a stupid question, but I've been attempting to get into C++ after just getting a handle on Visual Basic, so a lot of these things I am unfamiliar with. I promise I'm not just asking them to waste your time.

I've been trying to do a sample project in C++ to learn the basics, and I'm having an issue with the current code. The program is supposed to add up user inputted variables and take into account which month they have entered to apply different charges. However, It says that my variable, usageCost, hasn't been initialized. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string monthtext;
    double month,
        days,
        hours,
        kwhr,
        completeCharge,
        energyadjustCharge;

    const double flatservicecharge = 5.31;

    cout << "Enter the month (1-12) :";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Number of days in the period :";
    cin >> days;
    cout << "Kilowatt hours used :";
    cin >> hours;
    if (month = 1){
        monthtext = "January";
    }
    else{
        if (month = 2){
            monthtext = "February";
        }
        else{
            if (month = 3){
                monthtext = "March";
            }
            else{
                if (month = 4){
                    monthtext = "April";
                }
                else{
                    if (month = 5){
                        monthtext = "May";
                    }
                    else{
                        if (month = 6){
                            monthtext = "June";
                        }
                        else{
                            if (month = 7){
                                monthtext = "July";
                            }
                            else{
                                if (month = 8){
                                    monthtext = "August";
                                }
                                else{
                                    if (month = 9){
                                        monthtext = "September";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (month = 10){
                                            monthtext = "October";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if (month = 11){
                                                monthtext = "November";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                if (month = 12){
                                                    monthtext = "December";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    double usageCost;
    if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours <= 500){
        usageCost = hours * 12.9266;
    }
    if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours > 500){
        usageCost = 500 * 12.9266 + (hours - 500) * 10.9917;
    }
    if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours <= 750){
        usageCost = 750 * 12.9266;
    }
    if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours > 750){
        usageCost = 750 * 12.9266 + (hours - 750) * 14.2592;
    }

    energyadjustCharge = hours * .1305;
    completeCharge = usageCost + flatservicecharge + energyadjustCharge;

    cin.get();
    return 1;       
}
```

Comment: Why so many nested `else`, `if`?

Comment: set usageCost to a default value depending on what you want say double usageCost=0.0;

Comment: Why did you `return 1` in the end?

Comment: Also it would probably  give only a warning no compile error if you dont initialize , also this forum is not for debugging :)

Comment: You have to use `==` to compare, as in `if (month == 1)`

Comment: also try `else if { }`

Comment: This line: `if (month = 1)` ***assigns*** the value 1 to the variable `month`.  If you want to ***test*** the value, use `==` (double-equals).

Answer (score 1):

You declare:

```
double usageCost;
```

but as you can see, you don't set it to any value, thus it is unintialized.

Compiler is correct.

**Solution:**
Try:

```
  double usageCost = 0.0;
```

**Edit 1:**

### Other Issues with your program:

**Assignment uses "=", comparison uses "=="**
Please change all your `if` statements accordingly.

**Replace `if` statements with array lookup**
Adding the following will simplify your program:

```
const std::string month_names[] =
{"No month index 0",
 "January", "February", "March", "April",
 "May", "June", "July", "August",
 "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

// ...
month_text = month_names[month];
```

Comment: In the table version, `month` should be validated against the range before using it as array index

Comment: Agreed, but this is an example of usage.  Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader or implementer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have some code paths that never set `usageCost`. Rather than hide the error by initializing `usageCost`, it is better to fix your code which surely did intend to give `usageCost` a value in all cases.

In fact it is good that you didn't initialize `usageCost` because it meant you got a compiler warning to alert you to the later logic error.

---

`month <= 5 && month >= 10` is never true. No month is before June and also after September. You probably meant `(month <= 5 || month >= 10)`.  The brackets are important because you have another `&&` condition following.

However it would be better to avoid code duplication and avoid the possibility of none of the four cases being entered by rewriting that section:

```
if ( month >= 6 && month <= 9 )
{
    if ( hours > 750 )
        usageCost = ......;
    else
        usageCost = ......;
}
else
{
    if ( hours > 500 )
        usageCost = ......;
    else
        usageCost = ......;
}
```

With this structure it is impossible for `usageCost` to not be assigned something.

Comment: BTW, look into using `switch` instead of `if...else` for the month selection, or use a table as Thomas Matthews suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `month` to be a `double`.

```
double month;
cout << "Enter the month (1-12) :";
cin >> month;
```

If I type `5.5` for this input, you can see that `usageCost` will never be initialized to any value.

```
double usageCost;
// This will evaluate to false
if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours <= 500){

    usageCost = hours * 12.9266;
}
// This will evaluate to false
if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours > 500){

        usageCost = 500 * 12.9266 + (hours - 500) * 10.9917;
    }
// This will evaluate to false
if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours <= 750){

    usageCost = 750 * 12.9266;
        }
// This will evaluate to false
if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours > 750){

                usageCost = 750 * 12.9266 + (hours - 750) * 14.2592;
            }
```

Consider:

- Initializing `usageCost` to a *default value*
- using an `int` or similar for values that will only ever be "whole numbers".
- using `month > 5` as the true inverse of `month <= 5`

Answer (score -1):

I fixed a number of issues for you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string monthtext;
    double month,
        days,
        hours,
        kwhr,
        completeCharge,
        energyadjustCharge;

    const double flatservicecharge = 5.31;

    cout << "Enter the month (1-12) :";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Number of days in the period :";
    cin >> days;
    cout << "Kilowatt hours used :";
    cin >> hours;

    struct {int input; string month;} Calendar[] = {
        { 1, "January"   },
        { 2, "February"  },
        { 3, "March"     },
        { 4, "April"     },
        { 5, "May"       },
        { 6, "June"      },
        { 7, "July"      },
        { 8, "August"    },
        { 9, "September" },
        { 10, "October"  },
        { 11, "November" },
        { 12, "December" } };

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(Calendar); ++i)
    { 
        if (month == Calendar[i].input)
        {
            monthtext = Calendar[i].month;
            break;
        }
    }

    double usageCost = 0.0;

    if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours <= 500)
    {
        usageCost = hours * 12.9266;
    }
    if (month <= 5 && month >= 10 && hours > 500)
    {
        usageCost = 500 * 12.9266 + (hours - 500) * 10.9917;
    }
    if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours <= 750)
    {
        usageCost = 750 * 12.9266;
    }
    if (month >= 6 && month <= 9 && hours > 750)
    {
        usageCost = 750 * 12.9266 + (hours - 750) * 14.2592;
    }

    energyadjustCharge = hours * .1305;
    completeCharge = usageCost + flatservicecharge + energyadjustCharge;
    cin.get();
    return 0;       
}
```